# connect python to sqlite3 and fill multiple row in once

Tags: python, sqlite

this is not printing Error 
the value of `r=[bounch of number]` and dont know how many and value of result is the name of by `r`

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('/home/cbbi-l2-16/Desktop/karim')
c = conn.cursor()

print ("Opened database successfully")
example = [r,result]

for row in c.executemany("INSERT INTO Entrez (PuId,Abstract) VALUES 
(?,?)",(r,resul)):
    print (row)

conn.commit()
c.close()
```

it give Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sqlpython.py", line 60, in <module>
    for row in c.executemany("INSERT INTO Entrez (PuId,Abstract) VALUES (?,?)",(r,resul)):
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 5 supplied.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct usage of `executemany`. You can think of it acting like a nested `for` loop, where it iterates an outer container (representing a query) and then iterates the inner container which represents the data to be unpacked into the query.

However, in your case, you only have a single list, which presumably contains strings. Thus, the inner "for" loop starts unpacking the characters of the string:

```
data = ['hello', 'something']

for item in data:
    for subitem in item:
        print(subitem) # this is what it's trying to insert
```

This is the actual use-case for `executemany`, where you want to unpack the values inside the inner container:

```
data = [['hello', 'something'], ['goodbye', 'something_else']]
for item in data:
    for subitem in item:
        print(subitem) # this is what it's trying to insert
```

Just use `execute`.